# remove an item form a Listbox @windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

hey,
i m trying sice few days to remove an item from a databinded listbox while using the contectmenu toolkit.
the remove method ask me to insert the name of an item but i couldnt find it.

here is the function for adding the item

```
{
                listObjetDevis.Add(new itemListBoxSave { 
                 devis = tbCreerDevis.Text });

                IsolatedStorageHelper.SaveObject("devis", listObjetDevis);
            }
```

thx for help

Comment: which item do you want to remove?

Comment: well,i got a textbox which is databind with the listbox. when the user hold an item from the listbox, it shows a contextmenu where i have another button "delete" i would like to remove the selected item from the listbox and using the contextmenu. ty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how to do this which you should be able to customize to your own project/needs.

1. Create a new DataBound application.
2. Add a reference to the toolkit.
3. Add the following to the XAML declaration of MainPage:

   xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
4. Change the ListBox.ItemTemplate to the following:

   ```
   <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
           <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
               <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                   <toolkit:MenuItem Header="delete" Click="ContextMenuDelete_Click"/>
               </toolkit:ContextMenu>
           </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```
5. Add the following event handler to the code behind:

```
private void ContextMenuDeleteClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.ViewModel.Items.Remove((sender as MenuItem).DataContext as ItemViewModel);
}
```

Comment: i have already try this but Error 2 The type or namespace name 'ItemViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user569574 `ItemViewModel` is created in the ViewModels folder by the project template. See a working example at http://cid-cc22250598bf7f04.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/SO-4645170.zip

Comment: Is it possible to do the same using Command and CommandArgument properties?

Answer (score 0):

Just to state the obvious: if you're using `listObjetDevis.Add` to add an item, wouldn't you want to use `listObjetDevis.RemoveAt(list.SelectedIndex)` or `listObjetDevis.Remove(list.SelectedItem)` to remove the item?

Comment: what about it doesn't work?  The UI doesn't update? are you using an ObservableCollection?  If you aren't using an observable collection then the listbox won't be notified that something has been removed.

Comment: yes i use an observableCollection but when i try your solution, it tells to me that 'selectedindex" or "selecteditem" is not a valid definition etc

Comment: are you using ListBox?  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) or a `ListView`? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) Both of them does have public properties `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex`, so i'm not sure how you're using them.  To clarify: the selected items are on the **view**, and then you're removing them from the **collection*.